# Eigenvalues and Eigenspaces

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question concerning eigenvectors and eigenvalues.
Specifically Q7.

So I have already found the eigenvalues to be 1,3,2 although I'm not certain on how I can determine the Eigenspace for E.g. Eigenvalue 1.

Could someone please show me or guide through on how to find the eigenspace of the eigenvalue 1?

[image: q7]

Thankyou

Comment: The eigenspace is just the span of all the eigenvectors with a given eigenvalue.  Have you found the eigenvectors corresponding to each eigenvalue?

Comment: I've somewhat written the eigenvector although cannot justify if its correct or not. Could you please show me how determine the eigenvector and eigenspaces Please. Thankyou

Comment: Given an eigenvalue $\lambda$, the set of all solutions to the equation $(A-\lambda I)x=0$, where $A$ is your matrix and $I$ is the identity matrix is your **eigenspace**.  Can you solve that equation for each eigenvalue?  Hint: you can always go back to the basics and use an augmented matrix and Gauss-Jordan to solve it.

Comment: @Bye_World I think I understand what you're trying to say. Although I'm still confused. Could you show me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$ will be the set of all solutions to the equation $$(A-\lambda I)x=0$$

One of your eigenvalues is $3$, let's look at that one.

What we need to do here is solve $$(A-3I)x=0$$

So first off, what's $A-3I$?  It's $$\pmatrix{4 & 0 & 1 \\ -2 & 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 0 & 1} - \pmatrix{3 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3} = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 1 \\ -2 & -2 & 0 \\ -2 & 0 & -2}$$

Now we solve the augmented matrix equation:

$$\begin{align}\pmatrix{1 & 0 & 1 \\ -2 & -2 & 0 \\ -2 & 0 & -2}\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0} &\iff \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -2 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\ -2 & 0 & -2 & 0 \end{array}\right) \\ &\sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right) \\ &\sim \left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right) \\ &\iff \begin{cases} x+z=0 \\ y-z=0\end{cases}\end{align}$$

From here we see that $z$ is our free variable.  So let $z=t,\ \ t\in \Bbb R$.  Now we can write down the solution:

$$\begin{matrix}\pmatrix{x \\ y \\ z} = \pmatrix{-t \\ t \\ t} = t\pmatrix{-1 \\ 1 \\ 1}, & t\in\Bbb R\end{matrix}$$

Therefore the eigenspace associated with eigenvalue $3$ is $\operatorname{span}(-1,1,1)$.

Solve two similar equations to find the other two eigenspaces of this matrix.

Comment: So the first equation would be 3x+z=0?

Comment: Yes.  I'd suggest getting it into RREF first, though.  It'll make it easier to solve.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with the term RREF. Would -2x=0 according to the 2nd row? and therefore x=0?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.  RREF stands for "[reduced row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form)".

Comment: Oh okay LOL sorry i have no commen sense. So knowing now that x=0 , and z=0 how do we determine y?

Comment: There are no restrictions on it.  It can be any number.

Comment: Oh okay that sounds quite straight forward. Although on the solutions it is given in (0,1,0). Why would the solutions choose 1? I think it's because you can factor out the t making it 1 ? I'm not sure...

Comment: **One** eigenvector is $(0,1,0)$.  If your book says that the entire **eigenspace** is $(0,1,0)$, then your book is wrong.  The eigenspace is $\{t(0,1,0)\mid t\in\Bbb R\} = \operatorname{span}(0,1,0)$.

Comment: On the solutions it says the eigenspace is (0,1,0)

Comment: Then your solutions are wrong.  They must have meant $\operatorname{span}(0,1,0)$ but were being lazy.

Comment: Thank-you bye_world this helped alot. I might have more questions on Matrices later on the day. But for now it's 4am in Sydney and I think I'm going to sleep on this. So thanks again. And thank-you to thanaaisadr for your contribution!

Comment: Hey Bye_world can you show me for eigenvalue 3?

Comment: @RedQueen10101 Done.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Let $A$ be the $3\times 3$ matrix. If $\mathbf{v_1}=\begin{bmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$ is the eigenvector that corresponds to the eigenvalue $\lambda_1 =1$, in order to find the eigenspace $V_{\lambda_1}$ we may solve the system:
$$A\cdot \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix} = 1\cdot \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix},$$ with unknown variables $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

Comment: Yes I understood that, thankyou but how would you solve for x1,x2,x3?

Comment: $A\vec{x} = 1 \cdot \vec{x}$ is equivalent to $(A-I)\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. Solve $(A-I)\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ (a homogeneous system of linear equations) using row reduction.

Comment: @RedQueen10101 I see you are from Sydney. Is there any way I contact you for some info I want about the universities there?